# How to make uniques in Django Models? And also index a column in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

This is my simple Django database model. It's for a 5-star rating system.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    content = models.OneToOneField(Content, primary_key=True)
    ip =  models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

As you can see, it is linked to "Content", which is the table for my documents.
My question is:

- How do I make content+ip unique...so
  that it multiple content is okay, but
  multiple content AND IP is not okay
  (do not want the user to rate twice).
- How do I create a data-base index for content and ip...because I will always be selecting those (to compare if it is already in the database).

Comment: Why to use `CharField()` for IP instead of `IPAddressField()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regarding your first question:
You should look at [unique_together](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together), since this could solve your issue.

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    content = models.OneToOneField(Content, primary_key=True)
    ip =  models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together= (('content', 'ip'),)
```

Comment: it might be better to convert the IP into an `int` before storing, and use an `IntegerField`. it will use less space (im not sure why you've allocated 200 bytes to an IP address), and allow more query flexibility. 

you may also want to check out `django-ratings` (http://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings), which handles both anonymous and authenticated votes very well.

Answer (score 7):

BTW, if, as it appears from your terminology, you're using IP addresses as standing for users' identities, **please don't** -- it's a seriously horrible idea.  Users coming in through their ISP will get their IPs changed at random times, so they might vote twice; users on a laptop connecting at various coffee shops, libraries, &c, will have always-varying IPs; users sharing a connection (e.g., apartment-mates), or even every single one of users coming in from a University campus, might get the same IP address via NAT, so only one will be able to vote... it's hard to think of any worse way to represent individuals' identities!-)

If your use of the name `ip` for your "user identity" field is accidental and has nothing to do with using IP addresses there, I apologize, but in that case please do rename that field!-)

Comment: An alternate idea is to use a cookie or LocalStorage.

Answer (score 5):

About the indexes: you don't need to do anything for `content`, since it is a primary key, it will be indexed.  For `ip`, just add `db_index=True` to the `CharField` constructor call:

```
ip = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, db_index=True)
```

More information about db_index and other field options [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/fields/#db-index)

Comment: Indexing a second field will not make that field unique with the primary key.

Comment: I wasn't answering the question about uniques.  The second bullet in the question asks about indexing ip.

Answer (score 5):

This is the answer for those who are using Django 3.0+.

It's better to use [UniqueConstraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) ( as per the docs ) for making uniques.

```
 class Rating(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        constraints = [ models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['content', 'ip'], name="unique-content-ip") ]
        indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['content', 'ip']) ]
```

And hence you can define multiple constraints & [indexes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/indexes/).

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this metha keyword:  "unique_together"**

```
    class PowerBoardSwitches(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Switch id')
        powerBoardId = models.ForeignKey(PowerBoardDevice, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='powerBoardId', verbose_name='Power Board Id')
        powerBoardSwitchId = models.IntegerField()
        powerBoardSwitchStatus = models.IntegerField()
        createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created on date')
        updatedOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Updated on date')

        class Meta:
            unique_together = (('powerBoardId', 'powerBoardSwitchId'), )
```